# Oracle installer 12c :Insufficient disk space on this volume for the selected Oracle home

Tags: oracle12c, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to install oracle 12c on my server via X11 Forwarding (PuTTy and   Xming).

Server : Centos 6.9 (Final)

I get this error :

```
Insufficient disk space on this volume for the selected Oracle home
```

free -h

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers    cached
  Mem:            62G       6.8G        56G       568K       134M       5.8G
 -/+ buffers/cache:       919M        62G
  Swap:         1.0G         0B       1.0G
```

df -h
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The "free" command shows free *memory*  not disk space.  Use "df" or "df -h" to show available disk space.

Comment: Please note that CentOS is not a certified platform for Oracle 12c database server.  So, if you encounter errors, you can't get Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is your selected volume ?  "/home" is the only volume that has enough space.

Comment: /u01/app/oracle

Comment: /u01 would go under root which is only 3GB.  Certainly not enough free space.

Comment: You can't "edit" a filesystem size !  Another option is to build /u01 as a soft link into a folder under /home.  That would be "unclean".  The cleaner solution would be to create a folder path under /home and specify that as the destination for your Oracle install.

Comment: So the only solution is to install in "/home"?